# Angular router link "stops" working?

Tags: javascript, angular

**app.routes.ts:**

```
import { environment }           from './environment';
import { RouterModule }          from "@angular/router";

import { ContactUsComponent } from './static/components/contact-us.component';
import { HomeComponent }         from './static/components/home.component';
import { PrivacyComponent } from './static/components/privacy.component';
import { ProductDetailsComponent }     from './products/components/product-details.component';
import { ProductListComponent }  from './products/components/product-list.component';
import { TermsComponent } from './static/components/terms.component';

export const ApplicationRoutes = RouterModule.forRoot([
    {
        path: '',
        component: HomeComponent
    },
    {
         path: 'products',
         loadChildren : 'app/products/products.module#ProductModule'        
     },
    {
        path: 'product/:id',
        component: ProductDetailsComponent
    }
]);
```

**product.routes.ts**:

```
import { RouterModule }          from "@angular/router";

import { ProductListComponent }  from '../components/product-list.component';
import { ProductDetailsComponent }   from '../components/product-details.component';

export const ProductRoutes = RouterModule.forChild([
    {
        path: 'products',
        component: ProductListComponent
    }
    ,
    {
        path: 'product/:id',
        component: ProductDetailsComponent
    }
]);
```

**app.component.html:**

```
Welcome!
<br/>
<div>
    <a routerLink="/">Home</a>
</div>

<div>
    <product-list></product-list>
</div>
<div>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
<br/>
<div>
    <a routerLink="terms">Terms</a>
    <a routerLink="contact-us">Contact Us</a>
    <a routerLink="privacy">Privacy</a>
</div>
```

**product-list.component.html:**

```
<product *ngFor="let p of products" [product]="p"></product>
```

**product.component.ts:**

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';


@Component({
    selector : 'product',
    template : 
    `   <div>
        <a [routerLink]="['product', product.id]">
            {{product.name}}
        </a>
        </div> 
})
```

What happens is when I click on a product link in the `app.component.html` page, it loads `ProductDetailsComponent` containing the information for that product, but when I try to click on the other links again, the URL in the browser changes but nothing happens.

What I need is that on the first page load, say 'local.shop.com', a static component is displayed containing links to the products, inside `app.component.html`, and when you click on each link, it presents information regarding that product. I'm trying to avoid having to reload the page.

I'm not sure which more snippets of code are needed to provide enough context for this question, but please let me know.

Comment: How are you pulling in the product id in ProductDetailsComponent. You should be subscribing to the params so your component can detect when the url params change

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is due to angular component reuse feature that it changes the url, but doesnt change the view. You need to subscribe to the parameter received in your ProductDetailsComponent, and do something to it.

1) in your ProductDetailsComponent, import ActivatedRoute from @angular/route and Subscription from rxjs

```
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router';
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy} from '@angular/router';

export class ProductDetailsComponent implements onInit, onDestroy {
private subscription: Subscription;
productId: string;
```

2) in your ngOnInit, subscribe and do something inside it

```
  ngOnInit() {
      this.subscription = this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe((params) => {
      this.productId = params['id'];
     //do something here to trigger the changes
      this.product = this.productService.getProduct(this.productId); 
     //example
     console.log(this.product);
});
```

3) last but not least, do not forget to unsubscribe

```
    ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
    }
```

and of course, do not forget to call it in your constructor

```
 constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {}
```

Comment: I have been stuck on this for so long. THANK YOU!